# Discrete choice model: what value approaches the probability

Tags: probability

**Exercise:** A person is choosing one of $n$ alternatives. It is said that person's choice is based on utility function for which the following random utility model holds: $U_a = V_a + \sigma\varepsilon_a, a = 1,...,n$. Here, $\hspace{1mm} V_a \hspace{1mm}$ is unknown representative utility, $\varepsilon_a\sim iiGumbel(0, 1),\hspace{1mm} \sigma > 0$.

(a) What value approaches the probability $P_a = P_a(\sigma)$ of choosing an alternative $a$ when $\sigma \to 0$?

(b) Let's define metrics of difference for probability $P(\sigma) = (P_a(\sigma), a=(1,...,n)):$

Variance: $Var(P(\sigma)) = \Sigma_{a=1}^{n} (P_a(\sigma) - 1/n)^2$

and entropy

$H(P(\sigma)) = - \Sigma_{a=1}^{n} (P_a(\sigma) - \log(P_a(\sigma))$

It can be seen that the probabilities of choosing alternative $P_a$, when the uncertainty of choice, expressed through $\sigma$, grows, becomes very similar. Test this hypothesis using the afore defined metrics.

---

As bad as it sounds, I do not have a single clue on where to start.